# Como crio um sumário no texto com algum WYSIWYG?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

Eu gostaria de criar um sumário:

```
1 - Titulo Tal
1.1 - Subtitulo
1.1.2 - outro

2 - Outro titulo
2.1 - subtitulo
etc...
```

Eu gostaria de algo automático, mas não faço ideia de onde começar. Alguém poderia me dar uma ideia ou rumo para eu estudar e tentar fazer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com o HTML assim:

```
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
<ul>
</li>
<ul>
```

O CSS ficará assim:

```
ul {
    counter-reset: nomeContador;
}
li:before {
    counter-increment: nomeContador;
    content : counters(nomeContador, ".") " ";
}
```

E com o [counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) do css o resultado irá ficar assim:

1 Item
2 Item
3 Item
3.1 Item
3.2 Item

Comment: muito bom, nao sabia da existencia do counter no css. Segue modelo do seu exemplo http://jsfiddle.net/raHCP/

Comment: Não sabia da existencia desse counter, pode ser útil, irei tentar, obrigado Samir.