# Como fazer uma lista ordenada?

Tags: javascript, lista

Preciso setar um valor qualquer, e este valor deve servir como a quantidade de números em uma lista ordenada, onde em cada posição da lista deve existir o somatório acumulado de 1 até o número da posição

Uma dica de como conseguir já ajuda, pois bati a net em busca de linha de código que me dê uma luz.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. Seria interessante você adicionar na pergunta, o que você já tentou fazer para resolver o problema, e dizer em que ponto está tendo dúvidas.

Comment: Acho que você pode encontrar ajuda nessa questão: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8136/como-crio-um-sum%C3%A1rio-no-texto-com-algum-wysiwyg

Comment: Sem ver seu código ou parte dele, fica difícil.

Comment: Olá Ivo. Como tens esses numeros? numa array ou no HTML já gerado.

Answer (score 3):

Vc pode usar uma lista ordenada do html "ol" e os filhos seriam inseridos dinamicamente por um loop

```js
const target = 20;
const ol = document.querySelector('ol');
let lastValue = 0;

for (let index = 1; index <= target; index++) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  lastValue = index + lastValue
  li.innerHTML = lastValue;

  ol.appendChild(li);

}
```

```html
<body>

  <ol>
  </ol>

</body>
```